# Plot In one Gaph

Tags: r, ggplot2

How I plot the following data in a single:

[image]

graph in R using `ggplot2`

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: And what data do you want to plot?  Percentages or counts?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.